# Angular 7.2.5 + Typescript 3.2.4: Cannot read property 'aaa' of undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I have the following lines of code:

```
if ((this.axes.x && this.axes.x.property === 'run_number') ||
        (this.axes.y && this.axes.y.property === 'run_number')) {
        this.buildLineGraph(this.axes.y.property === 'run_number');
    } else {
        this.buildScatterGraph();
    }
```

most of the time runs without problems but from time to time fails if any of the element in the chains:

> this.axes.x.property
>
> this.axes.y.property

giving the error:

> Cannot read property 'aaa' of undefined

with aaa being the undefined element: axes, x, y, etc.

How do I check for every possible undefined element? Do I need a long chain of nested if statement?

Comment: Post the exact error message as it isn't clear what is undefined. It seems like it is `this` that is undefined(?)

Comment: I know, it could be 'x' or 'axes' or any part in the chain. I am asking if there is an elegant way to check for all cases. Apologies if message is not clear but English is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question but feel free to post a better and more elegant solution as a separate answer so I can vote for it.

```
if (this && this.axes && this.axes.x && this.axes.y && this.axes.x.property && this.axes.y.property) {
        if ((this.axes.x && this.axes.x.property === 'run_number') ||
            (this.axes.y && this.axes.y.property === 'run_number')) {
            this.buildLineGraph(this.axes.y.property === 'run_number');
        } else {
            this.buildScatterGraph();
        }
    }
```